# Objective-C, scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval Progressive Increase

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

I have a determinate progress bar which looks like the following:

```
NSInteger progressValue;
NSTimer *timerObject;

- (void)incrementProgressBar {
    // Increment the progress bar value by 1
    [progressBar incrementBy:1.0];
    progressValue++;
    [progressBar setDoubleValue:progressValue];
}
```

And then I call it by:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(incrementProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

My question: Is it possible to increment the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` for each iteration?

So for example if the `progressValue` was `1` then `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` would be `1`, but if `progressValue` was `2` then `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` would be `2`, etc.

Basically what I'm trying to do is progressively slow the progress bar down the closer it gets to `100`. There's probably some better way or recommendation for doing this, but it's essentially what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Don't use a repeating timer, just use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` in your increment method to fire it again with a different time delay.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-fireDate:(NSDate*)` to set the next date when the NSTimer will fire. For further explanation of the API, go [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/1407353-firedate?language=objc).

For example, you can achieve that as follows:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)progressValue sinceDate: currentDate];
timerObject.fireDate = newDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll give it a go and then get back with you soon.